# How do you make NLTK draw() trees that are inline in iPython/Jupyter

Tags: ipython, draw, nltk, jupyter

For Matplotlib plots in iPython/Jupyter you can make the notebook plot plots inline with

```
%matplotlib inline
```

How can one do the same for NLTK draw() for trees?  Here is the documentation http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.draw.html

Comment: It looks like it implements its own drawing stuff based on Tkinter. If that's the case, there's no easy way to bring it inline in the notebook.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24748479/232371) answer:

```
import os
from IPython.display import Image, display
from nltk.draw import TreeWidget
from nltk.draw.util import CanvasFrame

def jupyter_draw_nltk_tree(tree):
    cf = CanvasFrame()
    tc = TreeWidget(cf.canvas(), tree)
    tc['node_font'] = 'arial 13 bold'
    tc['leaf_font'] = 'arial 14'
    tc['node_color'] = '#005990'
    tc['leaf_color'] = '#3F8F57'
    tc['line_color'] = '#175252'
    cf.add_widget(tc, 10, 10)
    cf.print_to_file('tmp_tree_output.ps')
    cf.destroy()
    os.system('convert tmp_tree_output.ps tmp_tree_output.png')
    display(Image(filename='tmp_tree_output.png'))
    os.system('rm tmp_tree_output.ps tmp_tree_output.png')
```

Little slow, but does the job. If you're doing it remotely, don't forget to run your ssh session with `-X` key (like `ssh -X user@server.com`) so that Tk could initialize itself (`no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`-kind of error)

**UPD**: it seems like last versions of jupyter and nltk work nicely together, so you can just do `IPython.core.display.display(tree)` to get a nice-looking tree-render embedded into the output.

Comment: Do you need to add any configs/magic? Which versions of jupyter, notebook, and nltk are you running to get embedded tree render? I cannot seem to get it, just updated to

jupyter-client==4.4.0
jupyter-core==4.2.1
jupyterhub==0.7.2
notebook==4.3.1

I'm still getting tk errors: 

TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Comment: @GenaKukartsev make sure you did `ssh -X`

Comment: Are you saying I still need to do it for notebook? Just to be clear, I am not talking about command line use - that part is clear. What I want is NLTK graphics to appear inline in IPython notebook, similar to matplotlib graphics.

This may be a problem for my setup: I am running a multiuser jupyterhub ipython notebook server. Users log in via web interface. Given that, if tk is still needed to enable embedded graphics, I am not sure how to set it up. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `multiuser jupyterhub` - never used that; I'm just saying that console session that you used to run the notebook sever must have X session attached to it, if you're using Linux; and no idea regarding Windows

Answer (score 4):

2019 Update:

This runs on Jupyter Notebook:

```
from nltk.tree import Tree
from IPython.display import display

tree = Tree.fromstring('(S (NP this tree) (VP (V is) (AdjP pretty)))')
display(tree)
```

Requirements:

- NLTK
- Ghostscript

Comment: Perhaps you meant `display(tree)` instead of `IPython.core.display.display(tree)`

Comment: Not for me in Google Colab
`TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`