# Saving python NLTK parse tree to image file

Tags: python, parsing, tree, nlp, nltk

This might replicate this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429117/saving-nltk-drawn-parse-tree-to-image-file) . However, i'm facing a different problem. This is my working code.

```
import nltk 
from textblob import TextBlob
with open('test.txt', 'rU') as ins:
    array = []
    for line in ins:
        array.append(line)
for i in array:
    wiki = TextBlob(i)
    a=wiki.tags
    sentence = a
    pattern = """NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}
    VBD: {<VBD>}
    IN: {<IN>}"""
    NPChunker = nltk.RegexpParser(pattern)
    result = NPChunker.parse(sentence)

    result.draw()
```

[image]
This produce parse trees one by one for all the sentences. Actually in my "test.txt" i have more than 100 sentences. therefore, it's really hard to save each file into .ps files manually. How could i modify my code to save this trees to single .ps or .png files with a label (something like: 1.png,2.png ...).That mean i need to get more than one image files.
thanks in advance.

Comment: `result.save('something.svg)`?

Comment: No alvas . i got this- `AttributeError: 'Tree' object has no attribute 'save'`

Answer (score 3):

Although this is a duplicated question from [Saving nltk drawn parse tree to image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429117/saving-nltk-drawn-parse-tree-to-image-file), here's a simpler answer.

Given the `result` Tree object:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk import pos_tag
>>> pattern = """NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}
... VBD: {<VBD>}
... IN: {<IN>}"""
>>> NPChunker = nltk.RegexpParser(pattern)
>>> sentence = 'criminal lawyer new york'.split()
>>> pos_tag(sentence)
[('criminal', 'JJ'), ('lawyer', 'NN'), ('new', 'JJ'), ('york', 'NN')]
>>> result = NPChunker.parse(pos_tag(sentence))
>>> result
Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [('criminal', 'JJ'), ('lawyer', 'NN')]), Tree('NP', [('new', 'JJ'), ('york', 'NN')])])
```

Now do this:

```
>>> from nltk.draw.tree import TreeView
>>> TreeView(result)._cframe.print_to_file('tree.ps')
```

Then you will see the `tree.ps` file appears in the current directory.

Comment: Its done the trick... still its produce only one image.(actually its all away loop to the last sentence of the file) i need more than one image for each sentence in different names. how could i change it ? i tried in many ways. still in struggle.

Comment: @miller Try a for loop