# Is it possible to write nltk.tree.Tree.draw() output to a file

Tags: python, parsing, tree, nlp, nltk

Before asking this question i went through these( [question_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429117/saving-nltk-drawn-parse-tree-to-image-file), [question_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115282/saving-python-nltk-parse-tree-to-image-file)) , both are not exactly my use-cases

I am using nltk tree.draw() method to get tree visualisation of a sentence, but i need to do that for all sentences in paragraph

so i want to store the output of all sentences of a paragraph in a file, where i can preserve the representation and which will help in analysing those structures

the output through tree.draw is in this way [image: tree visualisation]

i want tree representations of all sentences of a paragraph in a file(text/image/ . ) so that it will be easy to analyse

is there an way to achieve that ?

**edit : output with treeview**  -
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gujqn.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Answer based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118789/9730177)
from the [almost duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429117/saving-nltk-drawn-parse-tree-to-image-file) you linked.

The `TreeView` constructor can take an arbitrary number of tree arguments:

```
from nltk import Tree
from nltk.draw import TreeView

number_of_trees = 14

# number_of_trees identical trees
trees = [Tree.fromstring('(S (NP this tree) (VP (V is) (AdjP pretty)))') for _ in range(number_of_trees)]

TreeView(*trees)._cframe.print_to_file('output.ps')
```

[Result converted to png from ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkHoL.jpg)

Side note: an alternative to nltk for drawing trees is the treedraw option of [discodop](https://github.com/andreasvc/disco-dop).

Comment: thanks @mcoav, but i am having a issue there, while i am printing to postscript file the nodes of tree are populated with some numbers and values in leaves are also  some strange words, i will upload output in question , please have a look on it