# Saving nltk graphs to file on a headless server/virtual machine

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtual-machine, nltk, headless

Taken from  [Saving nltk drawn parse tree to image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429117/saving-nltk-drawn-parse-tree-to-image-file)

I would like to know how I can save an image when using a headless VM/server? Right now I'm getting:

_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

```
from nltk import Tree
from nltk.draw.util import CanvasFrame
from nltk.draw import TreeWidget

cf = CanvasFrame()
t = Tree.fromstring('(S (NP this tree) (VP (V is) (AdjP pretty)))')
tc = TreeWidget(cf.canvas(),t)
cf.add_widget(tc,10,10) # (10,10) offsets
cf.print_to_file('tree.ps')
cf.destroy()
```

Answer (score 1):

So after a lot of exploring and experimenting with tons of libraries and approaches of getting the nltk parse tree from the string to a final image, the following is what worked for me:

**Dependencies to be installed:**

1. [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/howto/tree.html) - for reading a tree from a string and parsing it (as you've done).
2. [svgling](https://pypi.org/project/svgling/) - this library can read the output of the nltk tree and convert it into a svg.
3. [cairosvg](https://cairosvg.org/) - this library reads an svg and can convert it into anything from png, pdf etc. it doesn't depend on tcl/tkinter so no issue with a headless server!

**Code with a sample tree:**

```
import svgling
import cairosvg
from nltk.tree import Tree

# converts any nltk tree object to a svg
def tree2svg(t):
    img = svgling.draw_tree(t)
    svg_data = img.get_svg()
    return svg_data

# read from a string and parse the tree using nltk
t = Tree.fromstring('(ROOT (S (NP (DT The) (NN debate)) (VP (VBN continued) (PP (IN till) (NP (NN night)))) (. .)))')
# convert tree to svg
sv = tree2svg(t)
# write the svg as an image
cairosvg.svg2png(sv.tostring(), write_to='image.png')
```

The above piece of code worked flawlessly on a **ubuntu wsl** inside windows 10 so it should work for any server too (as I was facing exactly the same issue that you were)